# Java WebServer refusing to connect

Tags: java, html, server

I tried to make a simple java class that runs a server on localhost and just makes a page with the word test as an HTML title and the word test in the body. For some reason, when I run it and try to connect, it refuses to connect. Here's my code:

```
package Server.core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerListenerThread extends Thread{

    private int port;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public ServerListenerThread(int port) throws IOException {
        this.port = port;
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();


            String html = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>test</h1></body></html>"; 
            final String CRLF = "\r\n"; // 13, 10
            String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF + "Content-Length: " + html.getBytes().length + CRLF + CRLF + html+ CRLF + CRLF;

            outputStream.write(response.getBytes());


            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {


        }
    }

}
```

In my main method, I start a new ServerListenerThread on port 276.

Comment: Try printing or logging the error you catch in the empty catch block. What error is it?

Comment: It is a Address already in used: bind  error. I tried different ports and ran netstat to try and find if an application was using the port, but there was no application using the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to keep your thread alive. you can use while for that.
below is the basic modification i did. you can refactor more.
Also create ServerSocket once only.

public class ServerListenerThread extends Thread{

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    ServerListenerThread s1= new ServerListenerThread(276);
    s1.start();
}


private int port;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
public ServerListenerThread(int port) throws IOException {
    this.port = port;
    this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
}


@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // spin forever

        try {
           // ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

            String html = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>test</h1></body></html>";
            final String CRLF = "\r\n"; // 13, 10
            String response =
                    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF + "Content-Length: " + html.getBytes().length + CRLF + CRLF + html
                            + CRLF + CRLF;

            outputStream.write(response.getBytes());

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I already had the while loop in my main method, but removing the extra initialization statement did the trick. Thanks!